# SAS data reorgnization- linking information from one column to another

Tags: networking, sas, network-analysis

I have a dataset with a village name, market, churches, and hospitals. Markets, churches and hospitals are not given names directly; rather, they are listed by village, so that they can be directly linked to the village name. Coordinates are only listed by village. I need to reorganize a dataset in SAS, so that GPS coordinates for villages are linked to their respective markets, churches, and hospitals.

Here's a better visualization for what I'm trying to do:

Transform this dataset:

```
Long   |Lat    |Village|Market  |Church 
----------------------------------------
X(A)   |Y(A)   | A  |A  |A  
X(B)   |Y(B)   | B  |B  |B  
X(C)   |Y(C)   | C  |A  |A  
X(D)   |Y(D)   | D  |A  |D  
X(E)   |Y(E)   | E  |B  |B  
X(F)   |Y(F)   | F  |F  |F  
X(G)   |Y(G)   | G  |F  |F  
X(H)   |Y(H)   | H  |H  |F
```

To something that looks like this, with newly created columns for Market and Church coordinates (based off of the original village coordinates):

```
Long|Lat  |Village|Market|Market_Long|Market_Lat |Church|Church_Long|Church_Lat
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
X(A)|Y(A) |A      |A     |X(A)       |Y(A)       |A     |X(A)       |Y(A)
X(B)|Y(B) |B      |B     |X(B)       |Y(B)       |B     |X(B)       |Y(B)
X(C)|Y(C) |C      |A     |X(A)       |Y(A)       |A     |X(A)       |Y(A)
X(D)|Y(D) |D      |A     |X(A)       |Y(A)       |D     |X(D)       |Y(D)
X(E)|Y(E) |E      |B     |X(B)       |Y(B)       |B     |X(B)       |Y(B)
X(F)|Y(F) |F      |F     |X(F)       |Y(F)       |F     |X(F)       |Y(F)
X(G)|Y(G) |G      |F     |X(F)       |Y(F)       |F     |X(F)       |Y(F)
X(H)|Y(H) |H      |H     |X(H)       |Y(H)       |F     |X(F)       |Y(F)
```

I know the formatting is a little strange here, so here are a couple of images of these sample tables:

Original Table:

[image]

Desired Table:

[image]

Thanks for any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Include data as text, not images. If anyone wants to attempt a solution that they test they are required to manually type out your data.

Comment: As posted your new CHURCH_LONG is just a copy of the existing LONG column.  If that is all you want the the problem is trivial. If it is not then post a better example that explains what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented, the answer seems as trivial as just defining them asnew variables. As you are going to be defining the new variables anyway, you can use the length statement to set the order you want them to appear in the dataset.

```
data old;

input  lon $ lat $ village $ market $ church $ hosp $;
Datalines;
 X(A) Y(A) A A A B
 X(B) Y(B) B B B B
 X(C) Y(C) C A A D
 X(D) Y(D) D A D D
 X(E) Y(E) E B B B
;
run;


data new;

length lon lat village market market_lon market_lat Church church_lon church_lat
       hosp hosp_lon hosp_lat $ 100;

set old;

market_lon = lon;
market_lat = lat;
church_lon = lon;
church_lat = lat;
hosp_lon = lon;
hosp_lat = lat;

run;
```

This will work for a simple case but if there are many more variables than just market, church and hosp you may be interested in using macros and a %do loop to iterate over a list of the varnames instead of manually defining the new variables.

Great article for macro %do: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sastraining/2015/01/30/sas-authors-tip-getting-the-macro-language-to-perform-a-do-loop-over-a-list-of-values/

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. The issue is that the coordinates are only provided for the village. People in a particular village could go to any market, church or hospital- i.e., people in villages A, C and D all go to a market in village A.

The markets, churches and hospitals are all coded so that they can link with village names, which would enable me to link the markets, churches and hospitals to their correct coordinates. But coordinates will not be the same across a row, since a resident of a one village may visit a market in another.